# Performing Permutations and Combinations

Tags: python, pandas

so I have 6 Data Frames, each with 45 columns with the same headers. I give an example of 3 of them below:

**df1**

| **Name** | **Attr1** | **Attr2** | **...** | **Attr44** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Apple' | 10 | -15 | ... | 10 |
| 'Orange' | 20 | -20 | ... | 0 |

**df2**

| **Name** | **Attr1** | **Attr2** | **...** | **Attr44** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Cabbage' | 40 | -25 | ... | 10 |
| 'Lettuce' | 0 | -35 | ... | 15 |

**df3**

| **Name** | **Attr1** | **Attr2** | **...** | **Attr44** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Sugar' | 17 | -15 | ... | 8 |
| 'Salt' | 19 | 0 | ... | 12 |

Basically, the first column contains `str` data, and the subsequent 44 columns are `numpy.int64`. I am attempting to create a separate Data Frame which is populated by all possible combinations of the sum of the different rows of each Data Frames, for e.g.:

**Combined**

| **Name** | **Attr1** | **Attr2** | **...** | **Attr44** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'AppleCabbageSugar' | 67 | -55 | ... | 28 |
| 'AppleCabbageSalt' | 29 | -40 | ... | 32 |
| 'AppleLettuceSugar' | 27 | -65 | ... | 33 |
| 'AppleLettuceSalt' | 29 | -50 | ... | 37 |
| 'OrangeCabbageSugar' | 77 | -60 | ... | 33 |
| ⋮ | ⋮ | ⋮ | ... | ⋮ |
| 'OrangeLettuceSalt' | 39 | -55 | ... | 27 |

i.e.:
For the first row of **Combined**:
the *'Dragon SwordDragon ArmourDragon Boots'* for **Name** is given by the sum of (**Name** of the first row of **df1**, **Name** of the first row of **df2**, **Name** of the first row of **df3**) 
the *67* for **Attr1** is given by the sum of (**Attr1** of the first row of **df1**, **Attr1** of the first row of **df2**, **Attr1** of the first row of **df3**)
and so on...

For the second row of **Combined**:
the *'Dragon SwordDragon ArmourAres Boots'* for **Name** is given by the sum of (**Name** of the first row of **df1**, **Name** of the first row of **df2**, **Name** of the second row of **df3**) 
the *29* for **Attr1** is given by the sum of (**Attr1** of the first row of **df1**, **Attr1** of the first row of **df2**, **Attr1** of the second row of **df3**)
and so on...

So far, this is the roughly the code I have been using:

```py
count = 0
for idx1 in range(df1.shape[0]):
    for idx2 in range(df2.shape[0]):
        for idx3 in range(df3.shape[0]):
            new_df.iloc[count] = df1.iloc[idx1] + df2.iloc[idx2] + df3.iloc[idx3]
            count += 1
```

This seems to work fine when I am only summing 2 Data Frames this way. However, when I expand it to 3 and beyond, the order that the columns are returned is messed up. For example, the **Name** column which is supposed to be in the first column, ends up in the 10th column.

Could someone explain to me what is wrong here, what I can do, or if there are better ways to perform such a task? Thank you very much.

P.S. it is my first post here so I apologise if the write-up is not up to the standard or requirements of the community

Comment: do you have dataframes or just one dataframe with many attributes? If many dataframes how many?

Comment: I have 6 data frames in total, each with many attributes. However, the column headers are the same for each of the data frames

Comment: I'm having trouble following. Did you want the resulting dataframe to have a Name of 'AAA' and Attr1 that is the sum of the six dataframes of Attr1? If so, I would suggest joining the six into a giant temp df and then using a groupby attribute that sums by Name.

Comment: @rajah9 I have tried to edit the post again for clarity. Please let me know if it is clear now, thank you

Comment: Sorry, I don't think your edits have clarified your problem sufficiently. Please provide the desired results given the two dataframe samples as input.  This hopefully, will clear up the confusion.

Comment: Agreed, I'm still having trouble following. Is 'AAAXXXYYY' the combination of three different dataframes? You might want to take a look at the Python library itertools to help you with the permutations.

Comment: @itprorh66 I have uploaded an image instead. I really do not know how else to put it into words

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: @itprorh66 I didn't post a picture of a code. I posted a picture that draws out the idea of what I hope to implement, which I generated by colouring some cells in Excel. The code I used is what is given in the block above

Comment: @itprorh66 your last sentence is unnecessary. I have edited again, this time with 3 of the data frames shown, and the desired result added as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging with `cross` gives the "cartesian product of rows of both frames." Doing this twice gives us the product of all three.

I've used `filter(regex=f'^{col}(_|$)')` here to group like columns together... same columns will either have the same name, or be the same name with a suffix split with `_`.

```
cols = df1.columns # Assuming all three dfs have the same columns.
df = df1.merge(df2, 'cross').merge(df3, 'cross')
for col in cols:
    # We can sum both strings and number columns.
    df[col] = df.filter(regex=f'^{col}(_|$)').sum(axis=1)

df = df[cols]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                 Name  Attr1  Attr2
0   AppleCabbageSugar     67    -55
1    AppleCabbageSalt     69    -40
2   AppleLettuceSugar     27    -65
3    AppleLettuceSalt     29    -50
4  OrangeCabbageSugar     77    -60
5   OrangeCabbageSalt     79    -45
6  OrangeLettuceSugar     37    -70
7   OrangeLettuceSalt     39    -55
```

Comment: thank you! do you happen to know why the method I had used fails when summing more than 2 dataframes?